# How to determine which pins_arduino.h file is used?

Tags: arduino-ide, pins, port-mapping

For some applications I need access to the registers that control the output/input and high/low state of pins.  For example pin 10 on a adalogger is `PORTB` with a mask of `_BV(6)`.  This information can be found in `pins_arduino.h`.  For some boards many variants get installed.  I turned on verbose compiling and looked through the output there as well as looking through `boards.txt` and `platform.txt`.  In that output I see an include to a directory with a `pins_arduino.h` file but there is nothing in that file but a definition for `BUILTIN_LED`.

When I run a function like `digitalWrite(13,HIGH);` how does it know which registers to use for pin 13?  Since my board has this pin, and `digitalWrite(13, HIGH);` makes an LED light up ... it's working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the boards.txt file for the core in question you have a line for each board:

```
xxxx.build.variant=yyyy
```

where yyyy is the name of the folder in variants for the board.

For instance, the Uno, has:

```
uno.build.variant=standard
```

which relates to:

```
variants/standard
```

with the `pins_arduino.h` file in it for that board.

Comment: Thanks, I found that line and it agrees with the output from the compiler.  The problem is that particular file is basically empty.  Does that mean there is a default somewhere that it's using as well?

Comment: It's far from empty on my installation. What version are you running? And what board / core is it?

Comment: I have hundreds of pins_arduino.h files throughout the system.  My problem is with the adafruit huzzah ESP8266.  The pins_arduino.h file is basically empty.

Comment: Well, that is down to the core. The core most likely has defaults that don't need overriding. Most ESP8266 boards just map the GPIOs 1:1 and don't need anything else. Remember: an ESP8266 is ***not*** an AVR Arduino and does ***not*** follow the same rules.